# OpenGL ES 1.1 modulation and GL_RGB_SCALE

Tags: image-processing, opengl-es-1.1

In my Application I need to multiply two textures and then multiply the result by a factor higher than 2. I am using GL_MODULATE and GL_RGB_SCALE for this. I use following code for this

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Input.texID);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Temp64.texID);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
// glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Temp64.wide, Temp64.high, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_MODULATE);   
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_RGB_SCALE,   4.0);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);
glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
//glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

According to my understanding of the OpenGL ES 1.1 specifications first modulation between textures are done, then multiplication by 4 is done and then clamped to [0 1].

This is what the specification says

"If the value of TEXTURE ENV MODE is COMBINE, the form of the texture func- tion depends on the values of COMBINE RGB and COMBINE ALPHA, according to table 3.17. The RGB and ALPHA results of the texture function are then multi-plied by the values of RGB SCALE and ALPHA SCALE, respectively. The results are clamped to [0, 1]."

But what I notice is different. It first multiplies texture unit 1 by 4 and clamped into [0 1]  then modulated with Texture unit 0. But I want the RGB_SCALE to be applied after the modulation.

I tried to write the modulation results to a FBO and then to use scaling but it didn't work.

What I want to do is to multiply an image with another and then multiply the result with a value higher than 2. There shouldn't be clamping until the 2nd multiplication. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've had several issues related to texture combiners similar to the ones you mention. Modern hardware does not have a fixed function pipeline so all its functionality is implemented thru shaders and some of these implementations have unexpected results.

What's your target platform?  My suggestion is to get rid of the texture combiners at all and move all your code to shaders (if your target platform allows it).

Also, if I'm reading correctly your code, you need to place glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE) after binding the first texture so you can use it when you call glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS).

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) is also misplaced and it should be called before any other texture related function.